# Call an url to retrieve a list

Tags: php, web-services, serialization, php-5.4

I have a question. I need to get data from this url `/wd/biling.php?get&amp;id=1`.I now that this url return the liste `serialize`. I tried to retrieve by using `$data= file_get_contents('/wd/biling.php?get&amp;id=1');` but I have the error : `Failed to open stream`. Can you help me please ?

Comment: Not without seeing your code.

Comment: You have just supplied the path. So It's looking in the file system for that file name.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Failed to open stream : No such file or directory](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/36577020/failed-to-open-stream-no-such-file-or-directory)

Answer (score 1):

URLs can only be passed as absolute(with Protocol+Host+Path).
try:

```
 file_get_contents('http[s]://domain/path');
```

Also if your loading any local content this way, you might be doing something wrong. We use **include** or **require** to run local php files.
You can use this way.

```
 $id = 1;
 include('/wd/biling.php');
```

now in **biling.php** you can use $id just like that.